# Eloquent Laravel 4.2 setando Null em valores iguais

Tags: laravel-4

Estou com problema com o `ORM Eloquent` onde se eu dou `update` em uma tabela e uma coluna dessa tabela seja igual do meu `input` ele deixa `null`.

***Exemplo:***

Tabela

```
name    idade
joão    10
```

usando o comando

```
$user->update($input);
```

sendo `$user` o model da tabela usuários, se eu atualizar a idade para 10 novamente ele deixa idade como `null`, mas usando o comando

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update($input);
```

funciona corretamente.

Controller

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use \Carbon\Carbon;

class Users extends BaseController implements InterfaceController {

    use \Traits\UserTrait;

    public
        $rules = [
            ‘idade’ => 'numeric'
        ],

    public $model;

    public function __construct(Users $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
     }

    public function update($id) {
        $user = $this->model->findOrFail($id);

        $input = Input::all();

        $user->update($input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque também seu `controller`, coloque também o que é `$input`? Não entendi a primeira parte já visto que funcionou a segunda

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo do controller. Eu preciso da primeira função por causa do tipo da resposta. O primeiro comando devolve todos os dados do objeto atualizado, o segundo devolve apenas 1(sucesso) ou 0(erro).

Comment: Não faz sentido. Se eu trocar o $user->update($input) por DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update($input) ele funciona normal. Eu não alterei nada no model dos usuários. Eu precisei criar o método update pra alterar o que ele faz depois do update. Em outros casos ele funciona normal.

Comment: Entendi eu fiz uma confusão, o que retorna: `$input = Input::all();`???

Comment: Input::all() seria o array que foi enviado pelo método POST via formulário do front-end usando ajax.

Comment: Preciso saber dos valores dá um `var_dump` em `Input::all()`?

Comment: array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'João Teste' (length=10)
  'idade' => string '10' (length=2)

Comment: Poste o seu model?

Answer (score 0):

Eu realmente fiquei confuso quando você postou um método que já é implementado no `ORM Eloquent` e não funciona. Agora observando bem você não seguiu a nomenclatura de nomes que o `Laravel` deixa como exemplo, você criou um `Controller` sem utilizar o nome final, exemplo:

- UsersController
- CarsController
- PeopleController

isso é um forma de padronizar nomes e códigos referente a determinada área, não é regra obrigatória, mas, é uma boa prática sim seguir o que o `Framework` [deixa como exemplo na sua documentação e clicando aqui fica claro isso](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers)

Então o que aconteceu com o seu código dando problema, você criou um `model` `Users` e um `controller` `Users`, ou seja, está chocando nomes e por isso deve esta com problemas na gravação.

O ideal do seu código é renomear o seu `controller` para `UsersController`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use \Carbon\Carbon;

class UsersController extends BaseController implements InterfaceController 
{
    use \Traits\UserTrait;

    public $rules = ['idade' => 'numeric'];

    private $model;

    public function __construct(Users $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function update($id) 
    {
        $user = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
        $input = Input::all();
        $user->update($input);
    }
}
```

apesar que mesmo assim, eu não tenho o seu `model` para saber qual forma é a melhor para exemplificar pra você, então fica a dica, quando fizer uma questionamento, colocar tudo que estiver envolvido, `model`, `controller`, o que foi enviado da `view`pra o `controller`, etc.